# Get a frame from a live video stream

Tags: python, image, video-streaming, webcam, live

What would you have to do to get a single frame from a live webcam feed and update it repeatedly to a output file? I have seen this done before so i know it is possible. I want to use something like Python if possible but any help is welcome. Maybe this is possible using OpenCV?

Comment: The project where i have seen this was something with displaying a fishbowl feed on a webpage.

Comment: You want to update a frame repeatedly?  That's what video is.  Update it where?  What exactly are you trying to do?  What exactly is the live webcam feed?  (Format?  Protocol?  Codecs?)

Comment: Just use FFmpeg.

Answer (score 0):

This should meet your requirements of "Saving each frame from the video feed "

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import random

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

i=0
while(True):
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    i+=1
    cv2.imwrite('database/{index}.png'.format(index=i),frame)


    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

In Code . **database** is the directory where every frame will be saved through index(i) iteration.

Answer (score -2):

OpenCV should be able to do this pretty easily:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(True):
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    # Our operations on the frame come here
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Source: http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html

Comment: I have read that page but from what i understand it doesn't output it to a image file and that is what i want

Comment: It seems like http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/load_save_image/load_save_image.html would help, imma try the when im back home.

Comment: My bad. After the line where you get the frame, you can call cv2.imwrite("image.jpg", frame) to save the image. Of course, remove the while loop if you don't want it overriding the same image file.

Comment: Getting the frame, conver to rgb( i need that) and then imwrite